# How to move a star pattern horizontally?

Tags: c

I'm assigned a program which will show a star pattern as follows:-

```
*
**
***
****
```

And then it will disappear from its place & then re-appear forming a motion like moving from left to right.
I have tried a lot. But, The best I could get was to move only the first star like this:-

```
               *
**
***
****
```

The whole other part of pattern remains there.
I used delay function and gotoxy and clear screen along with `for` Loops but unable to do it the right way!

My pattern code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
char star='*';
int row, col;
int rowFinal;

printf("Enter the number of rows to be printed\n");
scanf("%d",&rowFinal);

for (row=1; row<=rowFinal; row++)
{
    for (col=1; col<=row; col++)
    {
        printf("%c",star);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Help me with remaining part I have messed it up won't be of any use to show it here.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Please, [edit] the question to show us the proper examples. Unfortunately, asterisk is a symbol used for formatting. You can for example select the stars and click "code" (the `{}` symbol in editor) to avoid that.

Comment: You can increment X after each pause, then gotoxy(X, y) and printf("**");

Comment: Help me with gotoxy function

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit ambiguous (please show code!), so I'm assuming when you say "assigned" you mean "assigned to make" not "given the program as a closed box and forced to work around what would be a fairly poor design choice if it is indeed impossible or difficult to edit".

Here is a rough framework for how to do it.

```
for (i=1; i<MAX AMOUNT OF STARS; i++) {
    printf(INDENTATION);
    //Code to print i stars and \n
}
```

The "//Code to print..." could be the code or the function call if by "assigned" you mean "given as closed box", but that works line by line.

Comment: By assigned I mean, given as assignment work to do in the institute I study.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is how to animate `*`, here is a small sample code with animates 1 star in 1 line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SWEEP_WIDTH 20

int main()
{
 int idx = 0, i = 0;

 for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
   if (--idx < 0)
   {
    idx = SWEEP_WIDTH;
   }

   printf("%*s%*s\r", idx, "*", (SWEEP_WIDTH-idx), " ");
   fflush(stdout);
   usleep(50000);
 }
```

I don't write the whole code for you, but I guess this should be somehow enough to get how you can animate stars in your code.

By the way, you can always code better if you spend time, this is result of 5 min coding, so you may be able to write it much better.